# WordPress Query - sorting by meta value but with a function applied to it

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting

I'm getting all of my events like this:

```
$args = Array(
    'post_type'         => 'event',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'meta_key'          => 'event-start-date',
    'orderby'  => array(
        'meta_value_num' => 'ASC',
        'event-time'     => 'ASC',
    ),
    'order'             => 'ASC',
    'meta_query'        => array(
         array(
                'key'       => 'event-start-date',
                'compare'   => '>=',
                'value'     => $startOfWeek,
                'type'      => 'numeric'
         ),
    array(
                'key'       => 'event-start-date',
                'compare'   => '<=',
                'value'     => $endOfWeek,
                'type'      => 'numeric'
         )
    ),
);


$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

This works great except if you look at my orderby clause, it consists of two parts - event-start-date and event-time. The start date works, but the event-time does not.

The reason I think is because this legacy code stores event-start-date as a timestamp (so it's an integer) but the event-time is actually a string! So I assume it will now try to sort lexicographically.

The time is represented as "10:00AM" or "4:00PM"

Unfortunately I can't change the system to store the time any other way, and double unfortunately the start dates for all events have the same time (the programmer only stored the date as a date, and set the hours to be all zero lol)

So I was hoping I could do something like this:

'orderby'  => array(
        'meta_value_num' => 'ASC',
        strtotime('event-time')      => 'ASC',
    ),

but i'm not so sure it's working - can I call strtotime on a string like "10:00AM" and it would work? Am I just going about my sort wrong? It seems that no matter what I put there, it's not sorting regardless (for the 2nd parameter in my sort array). The first sort parameters works and the items are definitely sorted in ascending date order, but just not in time.

Thanks so much!

Comment: You need to change the way you store the time.  Store it as a unix timestamp.

Comment: I want to, but legacy data it's still the same. Don't think there is a way to apply a function to the orderby?

Comment: No, there's no way to apply a function to the orderby.  As for legacy data, write a smalls script to update it to the new format.